# Can I apply same visa after I finish my 6 months visit visa in uk

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

good day I would like to ask if I can apply same Six months uk visa again in the Philippines after I finished my 6months visa this coming 22 of August? If not is there's another option that I can do dat I can come back in uk.  I also living with my fiancé at moment with my 6 months tourist visa...  Please I need ur advice.

Comment: Visitor visas are not intended for settlement. You should expect to be refused eventually, either for a visitor visa or at the border, if you continue this. If you intend to live with your fiancé permanently, look into a settlement visa.

Comment: I think the OP wants to do another 6 months visit to prolong the trial relationship. It's ok to apply in the PI as much, as often as you want.